# Upsource installation - features from tutorial are missing

Tags: jetbrains-ide, upsource

I am using upsource latest (bundle.build.number=0.5.362).
A lot of things are differnet than what I see in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QIu0ZjR96EY) tutorial.
for instance:

- When I click over a line in the code (browser) I dont get the option 'Start a code review'
- Browsing repository - When I hover over an entity in the code  I don’t see documentation, I can’t browse to its hierarchy. When I click it I only get two actions to choose (‘comment on selection’ and ‘link to selection’)
- I can’t browse revsions – I don’t have the link when I hover revision number.

My users are all granted with admin role (amnd developer, and viewer)

What am I missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Looks like you are referring to the video with Upsource 1.0 which is a bit different from the latest version. How to code review with Upsource - [the latest one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BCz5iFz9t3E)
- This features are only available for Java projects, with IDEA, Maven or Gradle build systems. Corresponding settings should be also set on Upsource side, in project administration.
- It might happen if revision is not indexed by Upsource yet